# Using multiple code generators in CMake

Tags: c#, cmake, swig

I am trying to create a C# application using SWIG based on a single CMake project, where two code generators are being called in sequence with a dependency tree like this

```
CMake Project A
  Target 1: Json -> C++ code generator using add_custom_command()
    L Target 2: C++ -> C# code generator using swig_add_library()
        L Target 3: C# application using add_executable()
```

The problem is when Target 2 builds, SWIG generates a number of C# files with unknown filenames. As a result we need to know all these file names in advance to build Target 3.

Can anyone suggest if what I am trying to do is do able in a single CMake project (A) or do I have to split it into two CMake projects (A & B) like this

```
CMake Project A
  L CMake Project B
```

with the targets split across like this

```
CMake Project A
  Target 1: Json -> C++ code generator using add_custom_command()
    L Target 2: C++ -> C# code generator using swig_add_library()

CMake Project B
  Target 1: C# application using add_executable()
```

Are there any know CMake patterns for using multiple code generators like in my case?

Answer (score 0):

After reading `UseSWIG.cmake` source I came up with following idea:

1. Figure out how target created by `swig_add_library()` is really called. In `UseSWIG.cmake` code it is called `${SWIG_MODULE_${name}_REAL_NAME}`. You can find it out with `make help`, for instance.
2. Read `SOURCES` property of the swig target: `get_property(TARGET <target from p.1> PROPERTY SOURCES`. This should give you a list of sources generated by swig.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but this won't work.
    
1) Yes that's how to retrieve the target name since it varies based on the SWIG target language that is chosen. For example, in case of Python the target name is prefixed with an underscore.

2) The SOURCES property is a list of input files, not the output.

Comment: Judging from the source, these input files are result of running swig.

Comment: No, these are the input files to the swig_add_library() function in the UseSWIG module. Of course the SWIG generated output filenames are based on the input class names. So one possibility is to run a script at CMake generation time to parse the Json source & come up with a list of C# file names that SWIG would generate.

Comment: Even the variable passed to `add_library()` is called `swig_**generated**_sources`: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/UseSWIG.cmake#L590 . Have you really tried this approach?

Comment: Yes I have but it's not a complete list as you expect. SWIG generates C++ wrapper code & target language code. 
The variable `swig_generated_sources` is made up of both of `swig_generated_file_fullname` & `swig_extra_generated_files` as in UseSWIG.cmake#L467. If your interface file is called example.i then `swig_generated_file_fullname = example_wrap.cxx` as in UseSWIG.cmake#L368 & `swig_extra_generated_files = example.cs; example_PINVOKE.cs` as in  UseSWIG.cmake#L206. Any other file names based on classes included in your interface file are not evaluated by the UseSWIG module.